# Multithreading vs virtual process

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, virtual

There's three types of control flow model, 
single threaded, virtual process and multithreaded process.
here's what has written in the power point which I study form

> Virtual processes.  This is based on a
>   single threaded model but gives the
>   appearance of concurrent execution.  a
>   controller component schedules the
>   execution of the other components and
>   gives them control. The scheduling can
>   be performed periodically or based on
>   events. This model is based on a
>   logical decomposition of activities in
>   simple steps whose execution requires
>   only short intervals of time.

I couldn't understand it and couldn't understand the difference between multithreading process and vp.
can some one help?

**EDIT** here the chapter of the book which I mention the section above form
http://www.mediafire.com/?ru82i0nvp12qw6t

Comment: Your question isn't very clear/doesn't make much sense... what do you mean by a "virtual process"?

Comment: Ok, I'll add more details ,just a minute.

Comment: Virtual processes sounds like cooperative multithreading.

Comment: what is cooperative multithreading?

Comment: You are not ahead with bogus terms like 'virtual process'.  Just delete that powerpoint file and get a real book about operating system design from your local library.

Comment: @Hans: Did you see where the OP is from? I'm going to guess that the local library in Gaza doesn't have any real books about OS design.

Comment: Can u download the chapter of the book I learn from , and search about Virtual process.
http://www.mediafire.com/?ru82i0nvp12qw6t

Answer (score 1):

This term "virtual process" is unusual but based on your description I can give 2 real-world examples of using each.

For multithreading, imagine you have a lot of data in memory and want to perform some calculations on it...  you can split that data up and have seperate threads (1 per CPU core, ideally) simultaneously working on different chunks of the data.  This way, the calculations will be done faster based on how many threads you create.

For 'virtual process', imagine you need to retrieve 20 files from remote servers... most of the CPU 'work' involved in this is just sitting around waiting for bytes to arrive from the remote network.  Creating separate threads to download each of these files would not make the files arrive any faster.  If anything, having extra threads that the OS needs to constantly switch between (and it will switch a LOT because most of the time each thread will just say 'im still waiting' and then cede control).  So, in this case it's better to have a single thread doing all of the downloading, cycling internally between each of the download tasks to read incomming data off of their buffers.

Comment: Many thanx but I don't know whether this is the right description, 
since in my descritption the model is based on logical decomposition of activities, so we can suppose that the activies themselves are not existed, they related to one real task, that's what I think, but I don't know whether is correct or no!

Comment: In this scenario, each file being downloaded is an activity

Answer (score 1):

Your *virtual process* looks to me like event driven programming. Google for eg. '[threads vs events](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=threads+vs+events)', the [first link](http://www.rlgsc.com/decus/usf96/ad019.pdf) you get is quite fine comparison.

**EDIT:** Here's another [comparison](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs240/readings/threads-bad-usenix96.pdf) I've found in bookmarks.